# I was banned from asking although I have a positive score here

Tags: discussion, questions

Today I wanted to ask a question, it turns out that I was banned from asking and the only way to regain the ability to ask again is to improve my existing questions.

- I have a positive score here, meaning that none of my questions are downvoted, I have only 1 closed question which I chose to delete because, because no one can answer it, so I chose to delete it and improvise my own solution
- My questions don't receive answers, but that doesn't mean they are bad, it just mean either they are hard or not enough users saw them or no one is interested, again none of my questions are downvoted
- How am I suppose to improve my existing questions if none of them are downvoted in the first place and only 1 closed?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have deleted questions older than 60-days that you can't find them anymore and only mods can help you?

Comment: @AndrewT. If such questions exists, I can't find them, nor remember them. they aren't listed under my profile, in any case, those that aren't deleted have a positive score, I mean I can't imagine the number of deleted questions one must have in order to be banned. I've been a stackoverflow user for over 10 years with tons of deleted questions, not banned there

Comment: 11 of your 20 questions have been deleted. That's a lot.

Comment: @fuxia what?????? Could you please let me know who's deleting them? Is there auto deletion?

Comment: Most were deleted by yourself, the rest by the community user, a script that deletes abandoned, closed questions without upvoted answers. Start by improving your existing questions without upvotes.

Comment: @fuxia I don't see how I could do that, they're too hard for anyone to answer them in the first place  that's why they'll be ignored like they are ignored now like https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308750/is-it-possible-to-combine-two-rest-endpoints-in-the-url and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308625/extending-the-api-i-created-to-return-category-names and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/305578/how-to-upload-multiple-images-using-wp-rest-api-to-media

Comment: @fuxia When you see that your questions don't get answers and people are leaving comments without answers, you might want to delete them

Comment: Questions regarding 3rd party plugins (WooCommerce, Yoast, Polylang, etc. ) are also considered to be off-topic. At least 35% of your questions involve a 3rd party plugin of some kind.

Comment: @Lynob your statement about wanting to delete questions when you dont get answers and people leave comments is probably what got you into this mess. Instead, improving questions and answering comments makes you more likely to get answers and upvotes. E.g. in your first example of an ignored question, it was never ignored. It's just that your endpoints were created by an unknown plugin. As a result what you asked didn't make a lot of sense. If you'd created the endpoints via code rather than a tool then the answer would have been super easy to give. In the strictest sense the Q was offtopic

Comment: As for the second question that got ignored, you said you'd try something then get back to me but then you never did. Now that I've seen both questions side by side though, I see that what I thought you were asking is not what you were actually asking, and that it too might be offtopic due to the plugin you're using to generate it. I thought you were asking how to upload files to create attachments, e.g. via the official core endpoint. I and others here have no idea what to do with custom endpoints unless shown the code

Comment: @TomJNowell there's no point in doing anything. Nothing would fix this. Regarding the api plugin it's impossible for me to create the api for a huge undocumented theme, so was forced into using it. I did ask about many plugins and when i realized that there's nothing i can do to recover my account, i stopped using stack exchange and gradually moved to reddit. The community there is good too like on WordPress subreddit, and they don't punish iffy questions with permanent bans. Worst case scenario is you lose rep, i don't care about my reddit rep, it has no value unlike stack exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things such as temporary bans are automatic. Having a question closed could have been enough to cause this to happen to you.

All you need to do is answer some questions that gather some upvotes (well-received answers) and that ban should lift by itself. It happened to me a few times as a new SO user. Good luck getting any upvotes; this community does not up-vote all that often.